# Youtube api search videos and q parameter

Tags: search, youtube-api

It seems that youtube api search video with q parameter doesnt work as search on youtube  wesite itself

If I search this channel for 'jorneot

https://www.youtube.com/user/GoProCamera/search?query=jornet

I get 5 search results (4 videos and a playlist)

But If I use api for same search I get only 2 videos:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id,snippet&maxResults=50&channelId=UCqhnX4jA0A5paNd1v-zEysw&key=API_KEY&q=jornet

Comment: Just curious - is there a reason why you use both `channel_id` and `q` (*if you're looking the same channel*)? - try search by q or by channel_id only and compare the results.

Comment: I believe this is suposed to be search q from channel, otherwise it would search everywhere.